# PrimeFaces confirmDialog difference between using PF('dialog').show p:confirm tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces

There seems to be two different ways of executing a PrimeFaces confirmation dialog.

I have been using confirmation dialogs using nested `p:confirm` tag as follows for quite some time:

```
    <p:commandButton action="#{businessUnitManager.deleteBusinessUnit()}" value="Delete" 
          <p:confirm message="Delete Business Unit #{businessUnit.name}?" header="Confirm Delete" />
          <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{businessUnit}" 
                target="#{businessUnitManager.selectedBusinessUnit}" />
    </p:commandButton>
```

```
    <p:confirmDialog global="true">
       <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="pi pi-check" />
       <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no 
                 ui-button-secondary" icon="pi pi-times" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

I recently noticed PrimeFaces showcase uses `oncomplete="PF('Dialog').show()"` in their CRUD example:

```
     <p:commandButton styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-danger" icon="pi pi-trash" 
         oncomplete="PF('deleteBusinessUnitDialog').show()">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{businessUnit}" target="#{businessUnitManager.selectedBusinessUnit}" />
     </p:commandButton>
```

```
     <p:confirmDialog id="deleteBusinessUnitDialogId" widgetVar="deleteBusinessUnitDialog" 
           message="Delete Business Unit #{businessUnitManager.selectedBusinessUnit.name}?" header="Confirm Delete" severity="warn">
          <p:commandButton value="Yes" icon="pi pi-check" 
           actionListener="#{businessUnitManager.deleteBusinessUnit()}" 
           process="@this" oncomplete="PF('deleteBusinessUnitDialog').hide()" />
          <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-button-secondary" icon="pi pi-times" onclick="PF('deleteBusinessUnitDialog').hide()" />
     </p:confirmDialog>
```

What is the difference?  It seems the later is more verbose. Is there a benefit to using the PF('Dialog').show method that I am missing out on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this one is slightly opinion based and depends on your needs, but I would alway try to use `p:confirm` tag handler in combination with a **global** `p:confirmDialog`. As you were saying way less verbose.

If you really would need customized buttons in a certain scenario, you could create a **non-global** dialog for that. As it's not global, you cannot use `p:confirm` with it, so you need to do use JavaScript to make it appear.